# I want to do new and create with the associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## What we want to achieve

Use the associated model to `new` and `create`.
The cause is probably that there is no variable set for `@movie`. So I would like to know how to get the id of Movie.

## Code

**routes**

```rb
# The routes are specified.
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # get 'movies', to: 'movies#index'
  scope :admin do
    get 'search', to: 'movies#search'
    resources :sheets, only: [:index]
    resources :schedules, only: [:index]
    resources :movies do
      resources :schedules, except: [:index]
    end
  end
end
```

**model**

movie.rb

```rb
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :schedules
end
```

schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :movie
end
```

**controller**

```rb
#########################################################
# I don't know what's going on here.
  def new
    @schedule = @movie.schedules.build
  end

  def create
    @schedule = @movie.schedules.create(schedule_params)
    redirect_to schedules_path
  end
#########################################################
```

**View**

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= render 'shared/head' %>
    <title>schedule/new</title>
  </head>
    <body>
      <%= form_with model: @schedule, url: movie_schedules_path do |form| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.label :start_time %>
          <%= form.date_field :start_time %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.label :end_time %>  
          <%= form.date_field :end_time %>
          <%= form.submit  %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </body>
</html>
```

## What I tried.

・`@movie = Movie.find(params[:id])`
Cannot be obtained due to routes.

```
web_1  | NoMethodError (undefined method `schedules' for nil:NilClass):
web_1  |   
web_1  | app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:7:in `new'
web_1  | Started GET "/admin/movies/15/schedules/new" for 192.168.0.1 at 2021-10-05 07:06:39 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 192.168.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
web_1  | Processing by SchedulesController#new as HTML
web_1  |   Parameters: {"movie_id"=>"15"}
web_1  | Completed 404 Not Found in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 1755)
web_1  | 
web_1  | 
web_1  |   
web_1  | ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Movie without an ID):
web_1  |   
web_1  | app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:7:in `new'
web_1  | Started GET "/admin/movies/15/schedules/new" for 192.168.0.1 at 2021-10-05 07:06:41 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 192.168.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
web_1  | Processing by SchedulesController#new as HTML
web_1  |   Parameters: {"movie_id"=>"15"}
web_1  | Completed 404 Not Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 601)
web_1  | 
web_1  | 
web_1  |   
web_1  | ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Movie without an ID):
web_1  |   
web_1  | app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:7:in `new'
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the view crash at `movie_schedules_path` ?

Comment: Please post a screenshot with the rails logs, when you submit the form to see the params. You should get a :move_id param.

Comment: Logs and images have been added.

Comment: It's `@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])`. You can see the param in the list. Because schedules is nested under movies, you get :movie_id instead of :id. The :id, when present is for Schedules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `schedules` nested under `movies`.

Running `rake routes | grep movies` you will see how the routes look like.

```
movie_schedules POST            /movies/:movie_id/schedules(.:format)                                                                                  schedules#create
new_movie_schedule GET          /movies/:movie_id/schedules/new(.:format)                                                                              schedules#new
edit_movie_schedule GET         /movies/:movie_id/schedules/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                         schedules#edit
movie_schedule GET              /movies/:movie_id/schedules/:id(.:format)
```

So your parameter is `movie_id` and doing `@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])` will fix the issue.

Here are the docs for [Nested Resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Answer (score 0):

razvans suggested in a comment that I use

`@movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])`
which worked for me.

Comment: @razvans  I apologize, but I appreciate your help.